# accepts_nested_attributes_for not saving nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I've been stuck on this one problem for days now. This is my first Rails app, and I'm almost finished, only to be slowed considerably by this.

I read that using accepts_nested_attributes_for is the best solution to my problem of nesting Ingredients within a Recipe for use with forms, but so far I have had no luck. I have read everything I can find on the subject. The API says the model now has a (in my case) ingredients_attributes= method, which I do not yet see. I have attempted using update_attributes in the console with the hash

```
recipe.update_attrubutes {:ingredients_attributes=>[{:name=>"Test Ingredient"}]}
```

This comes back *true*, but shows no changes in the recipe object.

I have attempted many approaches, my first being just using fields_for inside of a forms_for inside of my View. Since this wasn't working and I was testing the code to no avail, I started looking deeper and the problem definitely goes deeper than the View.

Any help would be much appreciated. My code follows

### Recipe Model

Sorry about the confusing conversions between the db-styled names and the display-styled names. This is my best fix so far to maintain the both of them.

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

  DISH_TYPES={""=>"", "Breakfast"=>"breakfast", "Lunch"=>"lunch", "Soup"=>"soup", "Entree"=>"entree", "Desert"=>"desert"}
  SEASONS={"Any Season"=>"any", "Fall"=>"fall", "Winter"=>"winter", "Spring"=>"spring", "Summer"=>"summer"}
  DIETS={""=>"", "Vegan"=>"vegan", "Vegetarian"=>"vegetarian", "Omnivore"=>"omnivore"}

  DISH_TYPES_R={""=>"", "breakfast"=>"Breakfast", "lunch"=>"Lunch", "soup"=>"Soup", "entree"=>"Entree", "desert"=>"Desert"}
  SEASONS_R={"any"=>"Any Season", "fall"=>"Fall", "winter"=>"Winter", "spring"=>"Spring", "summer"=>"Summer"}
  DIETS_R={""=>"", "vegan"=>"Vegan", "vegetarian"=>"Vegetarian", "omnivore"=>"Omnivore"}

  attr_protected :user_id
  # Do NOT include user_id in the attr_accessible method, to avoid
  # the possibility of it being changed externally.
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user  
  has_many :ingredients, dependent: :destroy # , inverse_of: :recipe

  # Allows for forms to write attributes down the hierarchy.
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, allow_destroy: true , reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }

  before_save do
    # Lowercase and convert to strings all of the attributes
    # that require a specific format, namely the values in the
    # constant hashes above.
    STRING_ATTRIBUTES.each do |s|
      self.send("#{s}=".to_sym, self.send(s).downcase.to_s)
    end
  end

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :name,  presence: true,
                    length: { maximum: 64 } #,uniqueness: true
  validates :dish_type, inclusion: { in: DISH_TYPES.values }
  validates :season, inclusion: { in: SEASONS.values }
  validates :diet, inclusion: { in: DIETS.values}
  validates :directions,  presence: true,
                          length: { maximum: 8192 }

  validates_associated :ingredients


  default_scope order: "recipes.created_at DESC"


  def method_missing (method)
    method = method.to_s
    if method.slice!("display_")
      if STRING_ATTRIBUTES.include?(method.to_sym)
        hash_name = method.upcase + 'S_R'
        Recipe.const_get(hash_name)[self.send(method.to_sym)]
      else
        method
      end
    else 
      method.class
    end
  end

  private

    STRING_ATTRIBUTES = [:dish_type, :season, :diet]

end
```

### Ingredient Model

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_protected :id, :recipe_id
  belongs_to :recipe

  validates_presence_of :name
  #validates_presence_of :recipe
end
```

### Recipe Controller

I've read that I shouldn't have to change anything in the controller. I have only added one line, so that the Ingredient form shows up in my view

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :edit, :destroy]

  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
  end

  def new
    if signed_in?
      @recipe = current_user.recipes.build 
      @recipe.ingredients.build
    else
      flash[:error] = "First you have to register! Sign up here and start adding recipes ASAP."
      redirect_to signup_path
    end
  end

  def create
    @new_recipe = current_user.recipes.build(params[:recipe])
    if @new_recipe.save
      flash[:success] = "You've successfully added #{@new_recipe.name}!"
      redirect_to @new_recipe
    else
      redirect_to 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id].to_i)
  end

end
```

### Ingredients Controller

I don't believe there is any use for an Ingredient Controller, since the ingredients (for now) will only be accessed through their parent Recipe.

I will include the views upon request, but as I stated earlier, I don't believe it is that high-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to set `attr_accessible` for `Recipe` model and add there `:ingredients_attributes`
2. As i see in your config, you have `reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }` for ingrediens_attributes and you are setting it only with name

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. I found that online, but I thought that :content referred to the entirety of the attributes content. I had that commented out before to see if that was causing the problem, but I still had it. It looks to be working now!!! What do you mean by attributes_acceptable? I don't see any references to that method.

Comment: That was a misstyping - i meant `attr_accessible`

Comment: That makes sense. Based on my recent reading on the subject, my `attr_protected :user_id` line is the opposite of the `attr_accessible` method, as it creates access to everything BUT :user_id. So I believe that is fine for now. Do you agree?